# Solidity function generic data type parameters

Tags: solidity, contract-development, function

1. I have two structs:
   `Struct A;`
   and
   `Struct B;`
2. I've two arrays:
   `A[] a;` and `B[] b;`
3. And a function: getIndex()

```
//                ^^^*Generic: based on struct type passed*
function getIndex(A/B memory [] arr, string memory _id) internal view returns (uint256){
    return 0;
}
```

As can be seen by the `^^^` marks in the function; I need to make function generic for structs A and B.

Comment: as far I know generic is not supported yet. but will be in the future. for now, you need to give 2 arrays as input and check which one is not empty